# Google Activity Recognition intent service doesnt work on certain devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a strange problem with google activity recognition API, my service works fine and detects activities pretty good on devices manufactured by Huawei and Samsung but when I tested it on 2 Motos and Nokia it didnt work. Huawei and Nokia running on Android 9, First Moto 8.1, second Moto 10 and Samsung Android 6/7

Here is my service:

```
class DetectedActivitiesIntentService : IntentService("DetectedActivitiesIntentService"), 
LocationListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
    private var monitoringIsNotStarted: Boolean = true
    private var tempDistance = 0.0
    private var maxSpeed = 0.0

    override fun onCreate() {


        mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build()
        mGoogleApiClient!!.connect()


        Toast.makeText(this, "Pracenje aktivnosti zapoceto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {

        if (monitoringIsNotStarted) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                startForegroundService(Intent(this, DrivingMonitor::class.java))
                println("FOREGROUND MONITOR ACTIVITY")
            }else {
                startService(Intent(this, DrivingMonitor::class.java))
                println("BACKGROUND MONITOR ACTIVITY")
            }
            monitoringIsNotStarted = false
        }

        val detectedActivitiesIntent = Intent("activityChange")
        detectedActivitiesIntent.putExtra("detectedActivities", ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent).probableActivities as ArrayList)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(detectedActivitiesIntent)

        val timeSt = currentTimeMillis()
        var actionType = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent).mostProbableActivity.type

        if (actionType == ON_FOOT)
            actionType = WALKING
        val lastActionType = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(KEY_LAST_DETECTED_TYPE, 3)
        val lastTimestamp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getLong(LAST_TIMESTAMP, 0)

        val preferences = getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = preferences.edit()

        if (actionType == lastActionType && trackedActivities.contains(actionType) && locations.size > 100) {
            if (actionType != STILL) tempDistance = SphericalUtil.computeLength(locations.toMutableList())
            var oldTempDistance = preferences.getFloat("tempDistance", 0.0f)
            editor.putFloat("tempDistance", (tempDistance + oldTempDistance).toFloat())
            editor.apply()
            locations.clear()
        }

        if (actionType != lastActionType && trackedActivities.contains(actionType)) {

            val preferencess = getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editorr = preferencess.edit()
            val temp = preferencess.getFloat("tempDistance", 0.0f)

            if (actionType == DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
                driving(true)

            var distance = SphericalUtil.computeLength(locations.toMutableList())
            distance += temp
            editorr.putFloat("tempDistance", 0.0f)
            editorr.apply()

            mGoogleApiClient?.disconnect()
            locations.clear()
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                    .edit()
                    .putInt(KEY_LAST_DETECTED_TYPE, actionType)
                    .putLong(LAST_TIMESTAMP, timeSt)
                    .apply()
            when (lastActionType) {
                //TODO Remove hardcoded values for max and average speed
                ON_BICYCLE -> {
                    if (!mGoogleApiClient!!.isConnected) mGoogleApiClient?.connect()
                    saveCyclingData(CyclingModel(lastTimestamp,timeSt,getAllUsers()[0],distance/1000,maxSpeed, 15.00))
                }
                RUNNING -> {
                    if (!mGoogleApiClient!!.isConnected) mGoogleApiClient?.connect()
                    saveRunningData(RunningModel(lastTimestamp,timeSt,getAllUsers()[0],distance/1000,maxSpeed.toLong(), 10))
                }
                WALKING -> {
                    if (!mGoogleApiClient!!.isConnected) mGoogleApiClient?.connect()
                    saveWalkingData(WalkingModel(lastTimestamp,timeSt,getAllUsers()[0],distance/1000))
                    driving(false)
//                    if(lastActionType == IN_VEHICLE) {
//                        rewardNotification(this)
//                    }
                }
                IN_VEHICLE -> {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        startForegroundService(Intent(this, SensorFusionService::class.java))
                        println("FOREGROUND MONITOR ACTIVITY")
                    }else {
                        startService(Intent(this, SensorFusionService::class.java))
                        println("BACKGROUND MONITOR ACTIVITY")
                    }

                    if (!mGoogleApiClient!!.isConnected) mGoogleApiClient?.connect()
                    saveDrivingData(DrivingModel(lastTimestamp,timeSt,getAllUsers()[0],distance/1000))
                }
                STILL -> {
                    saveStillData(StillModel(lastTimestamp, timeSt, getAllUsers()[0]))
                    Toast.makeText(this, "DETEKTOVAN STILL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()
                }
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                startForeground(1, createNotification(this,actionType))
            }else {
                startRecognitionNotification(this, actionType)
            }
        }
    }

    fun driving(driving: Boolean) {
        val intStart = Intent("QualityTracking")
        intStart.putExtra("driving", driving)
        sendBroadcast(intStart)
    }

    companion object {
        val trackedActivities = listOf(ON_BICYCLE, RUNNING, WALKING, IN_VEHICLE, STILL, ON_FOOT)
        var locations = arrayListOf<LatLng>()
    }

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        if (location.accuracy < 100)
            locations.add(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
        if(location.hasSpeed()) {
            val potentialMaxSpeed = location.speed
            if (maxSpeed < potentialMaxSpeed)
                maxSpeed = potentialMaxSpeed.toDouble()
        }
    }

    private fun startLocationUpdates() {

        val fastestInterval: Long = 1000
        val updateInterval = defaultSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL, (10 * 1000).toString())
        val precision = defaultSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.LOCATION_PRECISION, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY.toString())
        val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(precision!!.toInt())
                .setInterval(updateInterval!!.toLong())
                .setFastestInterval(fastestInterval)
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            longToast("No permission to use gps")
            return
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this)

//        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, LocationCallback(), Looper.getMainLooper())

    }

    override fun onConnectionSuspended(result: Int) {}

    override fun onConnected(result: Bundle?) {
        startLocationUpdates()
    }

    override fun onConnectionFailed(result: ConnectionResult) {}

}
```

Here is my service declared in manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name=".service.ServiceBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped"
            android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="RestartService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Hi! When you say "it didn't work" you meant that it raised an exception, the service crashed or it just doesn't do anything?

Comment: Well, sorry for my lack of info but yes, It didn't do anything. Accurately, it doesn't even start that service at all, I did put some toasts and prints in my onCreate and none of them showed on Moto and Nokia but on Samsung and Huawei they all showed up so its just that service doesn't even start thats my problem here

Answer (score 1):

Actually my problem was in how I call my service, after declaring broadcaster and made it trigger at specific events it started working!